# error code 4960 when saving a .plist

Tags: mac, launchd, plist, cron, bbedit

I'm trying to create a .plist file in textwrangler, something I've never done before. [I'm using these instructions](https://willchernoff.com/2013/04/23/periodically-run-an-r-script-as-a-background-process-using-launchd-under-osx/) which tells me to:

> Save code as com.rTask.plist file under path ~/Library/LaunchAgents.

So I follow those directions and it gives me the 4960 error. Here are two screenshots to give a visiual:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

I've done a pretty extensive Google search and still haven't been able to fix it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you save it to a different folder like Documents or your Desktop?

Comment: Works for me. Be sure to have write access to the directory (should be a given). How about using another text editor like Atom or Visual Studio Code to test its ability to save into this folder?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to create a launch agent with:

1. the wrong extension (*plis*)
2. in the wrong folder (*/Library/LaunchAgents/ (suggested by the visible plists: java oracle/microsoft? updater, google keystone and teamviewer)*)
3. with the wrong app (*TextWrangler*)

TextWrangler [isn't compatible](https://www.barebones.com/support/textwrangler/updates.html) with macOS 10.13. Download [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) or another compatible editor and try it again ;-)!

Comment: Haha that was just in the screenshot, but I corrected it. I was able to save it it to that folder but what's wrong with it? The tutorial makes it pretty clear I need to save it there.

Comment: @wizkids121 I think it's an incompatibility with APFS **and** root permissions. I had no problem to save the file to 10.13 HFSJ+ and a root owned folder (IE I had read access only)!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have overlooked the presence of `~` character in the instructions. You are expected to save the file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, **not** `/Library/LaunchAgents`. `~` represents your home directory which is generally `/Users/<your_user_name>/` directory.